# Display ProgressDialog from AsyncTask

Tags: android

I found some discussion and I followed [them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4538338/progressdialog-in-asynctask). But still have problem and the error at LogCat is, I think `Unable to add window`

```
04-19 16:50:47.835: E/AndroidRuntime(16147):    FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-19 16:50:47.835: E/AndroidRuntime(16147):    android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
04-19 16:50:47.835: E/AndroidRuntime(16147):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:712)
04-19 16:50:47.835: E/AndroidRuntime(16147):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:346)
04-19 16:50:47.835: E/AndroidRuntime(16147):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:224)
04-19 16:50:47.835: E/AndroidRuntime(16147):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:149)
04-19 16:50:47.835: E/AndroidRuntime(16147):    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:277)
04-19 16:50:47.835: E/AndroidRuntime(16147):    at com.test.MainActivity$2.run(MainActivity.java:213)
04-19 16:50:47.835: E/AndroidRuntime(16147):    at android.app.Activity.runOnUiThread(Activity.java:4784)
04-19 16:50:47.835: E/AndroidRuntime(16147):    at com.test.MainActivity.displayStatus(MainActivity.java:210)
```

My program is

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      }
      public class SSHConnect extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Integer> {    
           ProgressDialog myPd_ring;
           protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {}

           protected void onPostExecute(Integer  result) {
              if (myPd_ring.isShowing()) {
                 myPd_ring.dismiss();;
              }
           }
           protected void onPreExecute() {
              myPd_ring= new ProgressDialog(getApplicationContext());
              myPd_ring.setCancelable(true);
              myPd_ring.setTitle("Please wait!");
              myPd_ring.setMessage("Connecting...");
              myPd_ring.setIndeterminate(true);
              myPd_ring.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
              myPd_ring.show();

           }
           @Override
           protected Integer doInBackground(Integer... params) {}
     }



}
```

Comment: use `myPd_ring= new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);` in place of `myPd_ring= new ProgressDialog(getApplicationContext());`

Comment: I have answered so you can accept and i have also given a link plz go through this, this will elaborate why we shouldn't use getApplicationContext()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
myPd_ring= new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
```

In place of

```
myPd_ring= new ProgressDialog(getApplicationContext());
```

[getApplicationContext in AsyncTask class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15278840/getapplicationcontext-in-asynctask-class)

Extracted from the above link.

> " Why does getApplicationContext() not work from the UI portions of AsyncTask ?" -- because getApplicationContext() is a method on Context, and AsyncTask does not inherit from Context.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use.

```
protected void onPreExecute() {
          myPd_ring= new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
          myPd_ring.setCancelable(true);
          myPd_ring.setTitle("Please wait!");
          myPd_ring.setMessage("Connecting...");
          myPd_ring.setIndeterminate(true);
          myPd_ring.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
          myPd_ring.show();

       }
```