# Cannot resolve method getApplicationContext()

Tags: android

This is the code I got from internet which I need it for my own application. I am trying to make an app using the example. The difference is that I made one separate class for this named `JSONTask`. I am getting error with `getApplicationContex()` function. Please help me with this.

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.ListView;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import navdrawerexample1.models.MovieModel;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class JSONTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,List<MovieModel>>
{
private ListView lvMovies;
@Override
protected List<MovieModel> doInBackground(String... params) {
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {
        URL url= new URL(params[0]);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.connect();


        InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        String line ="";
        while ((line = reader.readLine())!=null){
            buffer.append(line);
        }
        String finalJason = buffer.toString();

        JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(finalJason);
        JSONArray parentArray = parentObject.getJSONArray("movies");

        List<MovieModel> movieModelList = new ArrayList<>();
        //StringBuffer finalBufferData = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i=0; i<parentArray.length();i++) {
            JSONObject finalObject = parentArray.getJSONObject(i);
            MovieModel movieModel = new MovieModel();
            movieModel.setMovie(finalObject.getString("movie"));
            movieModel.setYear(finalObject.getInt("year"));
            movieModel.setRating((float) finalObject.getDouble("rating"));
            movieModel.setDuration(finalObject.getString("duration"));
            movieModel.setDirector(finalObject.getString("director"));
            movieModel.setTagline(finalObject.getString("tagline"));
            movieModel.setImage(finalObject.getString("image"));
            movieModel.setStory(finalObject.getString("story"));

            List<MovieModel.cast> castList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int j=0; j<finalObject.getJSONArray("cast").length();j++){
                MovieModel.cast cast = new MovieModel.cast();
                cast.setName(finalObject.getJSONArray("cast").getJSONObject(j).getString("name"));
                castList.add(cast);
            }
            movieModel.setCastList(castList);
            //adding the final object in the list
            movieModelList.add(movieModel);
        }
        return  movieModelList;

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (connection != null) {
            connection.disconnect();
        }
        try {
            if (reader != null) {
                reader.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(List<MovieModel> result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    //This is where I get the error
    MovieAdapter adapter = new MovieAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.row,result);
    lvMovies.setAdapter(adapter);
    //TODO need to set data to the list
}
```

}

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15278840/getapplicationcontext-in-asynctask-class

Comment: `getApplicationContext()` is a public function of `Context`. You need an object that derives from `Context`, such as an `Activity`, `BroadcastReceiver` or `Service`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The trouble is that you are calling `getApplicationContext()` inside a Class that does not extend `Context` or its subclasses (`Activity`, etc). You should pass `Context` or its subclass to the `JSONTask`  constructor. Furthermore, I don't see where you are initializing `lvMovies` - and you are likely to get `NullPointerException` at `lvMovies.setAdapter(adapter);` - my suggestion is that you should pass this as well to your `JSONTask`  constructor:

```
private Context mContext;
private ListView lvMovies;
public JSONTask (Context context, ListView  lstView){
   this.lvMovies = lstView;
   this.mContext = context;
}
```

so that in the `onPostExecute` you can do something like:

```
MovieAdapter adapter = new MovieAdapter(mContext,R.layout.row,result);
lvMovies.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Your `Context` and `ListView` should probably be a `WeakReference` to avoid holding onto an activity depending on what context was sent.  Also  your list could be recycled before the task completes then you leak the entire activity the `ListView` was attached to

Answer (score 2):

First declare context,

```
Activity context;
```

then

```
MovieAdapter adapter = new MovieAdapter(context.getApplicationContext(),R.layout.row,result);
        lvMovies.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I hope this is helpfull to you......

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access `getApplicationContext()` from asynTask because `getApplicationContext()` doesn't exist in AsyncTask.
Make a constructor and pass Context to this class. Use it in your JSONTask class.

I would recommend you to use Volley library instead of AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0):

create a constructor and pass it a Context variable like

```
public class JSONTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,List<MovieModel>>{
public Context mContext;

public JSONTask(Context context){
    this.mContext = context;
}
.
.
.
```

now create JsonTask object from your activity/service as

```
JSONTask task = new JSONTask(getApplicationContext());
```

and now you can use mContext where you need to pass a context.